# (Swift) How can I detect/record the number of times a collisionBehavior has happened?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple pong-like game and so far everything is working well. However I'd like to count the number of times the ball has hit the "paddle" as sort of a high-score. Here's the code for the `sliderBar` (paddle) touch events:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !self.isBallRolling {
        let pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [self.ball], mode: .instantaneous)
        pushBehavior.magnitude = 1.5
        self.animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)
        self.isBallRolling = true
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: UITouch? = touches.first
    let touchLocation: CGPoint? = touch?.location(in: self.view)
    let yPoint: CGFloat = self.sliderBarCenterPoint.y
    let sliderBarCenter = CGPoint(x: CGFloat((touchLocation?.x)!), y: yPoint)
    self.sliderBar.center = sliderBarCenter
    self.animator.updateItem(usingCurrentState: self.sliderBar)
}

func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item1: UIDynamicItem, with item2: UIDynamicItem, at p: CGPoint) {

    let pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [self.ball], mode: .instantaneous)
    pushBehavior.angle = 0.0
    pushBehavior.magnitude = 0.75
    self.animator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)
}



// The label that displays the score
let countLabel: UILabel = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50)
    let cl = UILabel(frame: frame)
    cl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    cl.text = ""
    cl.textColor = UIColor.red
    cl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return cl
}()

func setupCountLabel() {
    countLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    countLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.sliderBar.topAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true
    countLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    countLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 73).isActive = true
}
```

I've never worked with `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate` before - where and how should I be detecting the amount of times the ball has hit the `sliderBar`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with that delegate either, but have you tried just storing a `count: Int` and incrementing it inside of `collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor...`?

Comment: What am I counting though? The number of times that function is called? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, just increment inside the function, so you know how many times the function is called. Maybe you only want some of the times, I don't know, but if so you can just wrap it in an if statement.

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the tip. I just made a `var count = 1` then put `count +=1` inside that function and set `countLabel.text = String(count)`